# Solve this linear differential equation.?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$S'(t) = 2 - \frac {S(t) }{(100 + t)}$$

Assuming $100 + t$ is positive

I got the integrating factor is $e^{\ln(100 +t)}$

Then 
$$s(t) (100 + t) = \int 2(100 +t)\ dt$$

So $$s(t) = {200t +t^2 \over 100 + t} + {c \over 100+t}$$

But my book says it's $$s(t) = {100 + t} + {c \over 100+t}$$

Comment: Where are you stuck? What method(s) have you learned so far?

Comment: is it on the right side $\frac {2-s}{100+t}$ or is it $2-\frac s{100+t}$ ??,

Comment: Well seems ok to me +1

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this
$$S'(t) = 2 - \frac {s(t) }{ (100 + t)}$$
$$100S'(t)+S't +S= 200+2t $$
$$100S'(t)+(tS(t))'= 200+2t $$
Integrate
$$100S(t)+tS(t)= 200t+t^2+K $$
$$S(t)= 100+t+\frac K {100+t}$$

---

Edit

Your answer is correct...

Both answers are the same

$$s(t) = {200t +t^2 \over 100 + t} + {c \over 100+t}$$
$$s(t) = {100t+ 100t +t^2 \over 100 + t} + {c \over 100+t}$$
$$s(t) =t+ {100t \over 100 + t} + {c \over 100+t}$$
$$s(t) =t+ {100t +c\over 100 + t} $$
Substitute $c=10 000+K$ it's just a constant
$$s(t) =t+ {100t +10000+K\over 100 + t} $$
$$s(t) =t+ 100+{K\over 100 + t} $$

Comment: How come it's different from my books answer

Comment: Whats the book 's answer ? @EdonKnoul

Comment: I've edited the question to include the answer

Comment: Both answers are the same @EdonKnoul

Comment: Why is that? I don't see it.

Comment: I added some lines I hope it helps @EdonKnoul

Comment: Oh my god thank you.

Comment: @EdonKnoul you're welcome you did a good job don't worry

Answer (score 0):

Yep:  your answer is correct:

$$S(t) = \frac{c_1}{t+100}+\frac{t^2+200 t}{t+100}$$